# cluster.initial_master_nodes for ElasticSearch on EC2 with Auto Scaling (after upgrade to ES 7+)

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-ec2, terraform

Trying to upgrade ES from 6.8 to 8.9 for ES running on EC2 AWS instances.
The issue is within `cluster.initial_master_nodes`. I see that I set fixed values for `node.name`. However, the instances are created by Auto Scaling group (Terraform configs), the ES template is one per group and I don't see the possibility of passing the index count of the instance created.

We need a scaling group to ensure there’s always the same number of instances at any given time. And looks like there’s no other way to achieve that.

Previously (in ES 6.8), `cluster.initial_master_nodes` wasn't needed and `node.name` was just set to `${HOSTNAME}`.

Any ideas?..

elasticsearch.yml in cloudconfig:

```
write_files:
  - path: "/elasticsearch/config/elasticsearch.yml"
    content: |
      cluster.name: ${cluster_name}
      cluster.routing.allocation.awareness.attributes: aws_availability_zone
      cloud.node.auto_attributes: true
      xpack.security.http.ssl.enabled: false
      xpack.security.enabled: false
      network.host: 0.0.0.0
      network.publish_host: _ec2_
      http.port: 9200
      http.compression: true
      transport.port: 9300
      discovery.seed_providers: ec2
      discovery.ec2.availability_zones: ${availability_zones}
      discovery.ec2.protocol: http
      discovery.ec2.host_type: private_ip
      discovery.ec2.endpoint: ${aws_ec2_endpoint}
      discovery.ec2.tag.ProductCode: ${product_code_tag}
      discovery.ec2.tag.role: ${master_node}
      discovery.ec2.tag.Environment: ${environment_tag}
      discovery.ec2.tag.InventoryCode: ${inventory_code_tag}
      logger.discovery: DEBUG
      node.name: $${HOSTNAME} # used to be hostname but needs to be pre-fixed now 
      #so I can use it in cluster.initial_master_nodes:
      #cluster.initial_master_nodes: need_something_here
      node.roles: ${node_roles}
      script.painless.regex.enabled: true
      thread_pool.search.size: 200
      thread_pool.search.queue_size: 20000
      thread_pool.write.size: ${bulk_threads_size}
      thread_pool.write.queue_size: 20000
```

Terraform configs:

```
data "template_file" "master-es" {
  template = file("es-cloud-config.yaml")
  vars = {

    //Elasticsearch
    cluster_name            = var.cluster_name
    heap_size               = var.master_heap_size
    availability_zones      = join(",", data.aws_availability_zones.available.names)
    min_master_nodes        = module.min-master-nodes.value
    master_node             = "true"
    data_node               = "false"
    docker_elasticsearch_tag= var.docker_elasticsearch_tag
    bulk_threads_size       = var.master_bulk_threads_size
  }

}

resource "aws_launch_configuration" "master-es" {
  count                = var.master_nodes_count > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name_prefix          = "my-master"
  image_id             = module.ami.ami_id
  instance_type        = var.master_instance_type
  security_groups      = var.my_security_groups
  user_data            = data.template_file.master-es.rendered
  key_name             = var.ssh_key
  iam_instance_profile = aws_iam_instance_profile.default.name
  enable_monitoring    = true

  root_block_device {
    volume_size = var.master_storage["volume_size"]
    volume_type = var.master_storage["volume_type"]
    iops = var.master_storage["volume_iops"]
    delete_on_termination = "true"
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }

}

resource "aws_autoscaling_group" "master-es" {
  count                     = var.master_nodes_count > 0 ? 1 : 0
  name                      = aws_launch_configuration.master-es[0].name
  min_size                  = var.master_nodes_count
  max_size                  = var.master_nodes_count
  desired_capacity          = var.master_nodes_count
  force_delete              = true
  launch_configuration      = aws_launch_configuration.master-es[0].id
  load_balancers            = [aws_elb.master-es[count.index].id]
  vpc_zone_identifier       = var.my_subnets
  termination_policies      = var.my_policies
  wait_for_capacity_timeout = var.master_capacity_timeout
  min_elb_capacity          = var.master_nodes_count
  health_check_type         = "EC2"

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}
```

The template file is a part of a launch config for a scaling group so there's only one template for all. I don't see a way of getting count.index for every instance created.

I know the hostname looks like “ip-${privateIP}.ec2.internal”. If I knew IPs, I could set that list. But then I need the list for the configuration of the instance...

Comment: Well, if the launch configuration will be different, you could use e.g., `aws_launch_configuration.master-es[count.index].name`, but for that you would need to set `count = var.msater_nodes_count > 0 ? length(var.master_nodes_count) : 0`. I'm not sure though if I understood what you are asking.

Comment: but AWS Scaling Group can only have one launch configuration, isn't it?